# Explicit line joining in Python

Tags: python, string

I am reading a file, line-by-line and doing some text processing in order to get output in a certain format
My string processing code goes as follows:

```
file1=open('/myfolder/testfile.txt')
scanlines=file1.readlines()
string = ''

 for line in scanlines:
    if line.startswith('>from'):
         continue
    if line.startswith('*'):
        continue
    string.join(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

The output of this code is as follows:

abc

def

ghi

Is there a way to join these physical lines into one logical line, e.g:

abcdefghi

Basically, how can I concatenate multiple strings into one large string?

If I was reading from a file with very long strings is there the risk of an overflow by concatenating multiple physical lines into one logical line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleaning things up a bit, it would be easiest to append to array and then return the result

```
def joinfile(filename) :
   sarray = []
   with open(filename) as fd :
       for line in fd :
           if line.startswith('>from') or line.startswith('*'):
               continue
          sarray.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
   return ''.join(sarray)
```

If you wanted to get really cute you could also do the following:

```
fd = open(filename)
str = ''.join([line.rstrip('\n') for line in fd if not (line.startswith('>from') or line.startswith('*'))])
```

Yes of course you could read a file big enough to overflow memory.

Comment: thank you, the array method more or less sorted out my problem! Can I ask, since I want to do this on files with very long lines, is there a way to go around the overflow problem. My strings will reach several hundred characters in length..

Comment: Python lists are not arrays. They are lists. Also, you don't need the square brackets.

Comment: @Spyros You're unlikely to encounter an overflow if you can read the file into memory with no issue... These days were talking files on the order of Gigabytes in size.

Comment: @pillmuncher [From wikipedia] An array type is a data type that is meant to describe a collection of elements (values or variables), each selected by one or more indices that can be computed at run time by the program. Such a collection is usually called an array variable, array value, or simply array.

Comment: But in Python it's still called a list. Also, the word _array_ has some connotations that are simply wrong for Python's list type, such as: array elements are all of the same type, arrays have a fixed size, arrays can have multiple dimensions, etc. None of that is true for Python lists.

Answer (score 5):

there are several ways to do this. for example just using `+` should do the trick.

"abc" + "def" # produces "abcdef"

If you try to concatenate multiple strings you can do this with the join method:

```
', '.join(('abc', 'def', 'ghi')) # produces 'abc, def, ghi'
```

If you want no delimiter, use the empty string `''.join()` method.

Comment: Thank you, the ''.join() function sorted it out, I put them into an array as koblas above suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Use string addition

```
>>> s = 'a'
>>> s += 'b'
>>> s
'ab'
```

Comment: You should not use += to concatenate many strings, though. Each += creates a new string. Collecting them in a list and calling join is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer:

```
oneLine = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, \
                 [line[:-1] for line in open('/myfolder/testfile.txt') 
                            if not line.startswith('>from') and \
                               not line.startswith('*')])
```

- `line[:-1]` in order to remove all the `\n`
- the second argument of `reduce` is a list comprehension which extracts all the lines you are interested in and removes the `\n` from the lines.
- the reduce (just if you actually need that) to make one string from the list of strings.